# Redirect to a page with api response in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an api controller with a http `GET` method. This method is invoked from a frontend. In response to this, I want to redirect user to dashboard page and also provide some login response object. When a request comes into this method, it comes from a different page.

The request comes to this method with a path `api/accounts/loginobject` when a third party identity servers sends oauth2 authentication. This is a redirect url method.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("LoginObject")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> getLoginObject()
    {
        var externalLoginInfo = await this.signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        // parse token here
    }
```

I tried below code and it works. But I don't know if we can send response object in the below response. I want to attach token in the headers and some info in the response body.

```
// dashboard is a ui page not another controller action
return Redirect("/dashboard");
```

The front end app is an angular app part of ASP.NET Core MVC project. I have a third party identity server which sends oauth2 result back to this controller.

The following will set header but it will be lost when the redirection to html page /dashboard happens. Still I am not able to respond to ui with access token

```
this.Response.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
```

Update:

I solved this temporarily by passing token in query string. It looks more like a hack for now. Once received it in ui, i will set it in web app local storage for subsequent api calls.

```
https://mywebsite/accesstokencallback?access_token=eybcsdfk23klsd-3dsfjs
```

Comment: A redirect just tells the client that it needs to send a new HTTP request to the location provided by your redirect. The client can then choose to follow that redirect (browsers typically follow these automatically) and send a new HTTP request to the location specified by the redirect, at which point your server can return whatever it wants to in the response. If you're doing an API controller though, it's likely that your client won't be a browser, so what exactly are you trying to implement here?

Comment: The front end app is an angular app

Comment: A http redirect can't include a payload. Looks like you'll need two actions.

Comment: r u using area ??